# How to create a json object from predefined json template in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am working in node.js. I get a json object from a service with some fields say:

```
{
  user: {
    firstname : 'John',
    lastname : 'Doe',
    emailaddress : 'john.doe@example.com',
    contactnumber: '9876458910'
  }
}
```

The above json data is fetched from a excel/csv file and converted to json data.
But the json structure of another service which stores this data into database has another format say,

```
{
  user : {     
    name: {
      firstname : 'John',
      lastname : 'Doe'
    },
    emailaddress : [{
      emailaddress : 'john.doe@example.com'
    }],
    conatactdetails:[{
      contactnumber : '9876458910'
    }]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this transformation

Comment: you can use some libraries like **lodash** https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#pluck with which you can easily convert any type of json with your requiring json. see functions like _.pluck in the documentation.

Comment: Or you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Is your question "how to", as in the title, or "is it possible" as in the question? Anyway, yes, it's possible. Write an object as you have in the desired format, and replace the fixed values such as 'John' with references to your input object, as in `obj.user.firstname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not *pretty*, but this will do:

```
function constructUserForDb(data) {
  return Object.keys(data.user).reduce(function(acc, key) {
    var value = data.user[key];
    if (key === 'firstname' || key === 'lastname') {
      acc['name'] = acc['name'] || {};
      acc['name'][key] = value;
    }
    if (key === 'emailaddress') {
      acc[key] = [{ emailaddress: value }];
    }
    if (key === 'contactnumber') {
      acc['contactdetails'] = [{ contactnumber: value }];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
};
```

Working jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/osse8p0z/).